# No ssl on php commandline

Tags: php, ssl, command-line, xampp

I have a php script that works perfectly on the browser BUT it has this error on windows command line.

[image]

I have ssl enabled in php config and from what I gather it works for browser but not command line but I don't understand the difference between these two (neither is windows service I belive). Basicly I don't know what to do about it and I need to run the script from commandline, then create .bat file (in order to start windows scheduler - like cron under linux).

I have windows Xp and Xampp. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that the CLI is using the same php.ini as your webserver? use `php -i` to check

Comment: Good Shot my friend! Please add this as solution so I could accept and give you +1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment above. Php in command line uses different php.ini config.